# error installing wordpress from bitnami web

Tags: wordpress, xampp

i have installed xampp-win32-7.0.1-0-VC14-installer but before that there's a massage that UAC will interrupt my installation but i ignore this warning and then i try to install bitnami-wordpress-4.4.1-0-module-windows-installer in the end of installing i got a massage "Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly Error running C:\xampp\php\php -c "C:\xampp\apps\WORDPR-1\scripts\createdb.php":PHP fatal error: uncaught error:call to undefined function mysql_connect()in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\scripts\createdb.php:8 stack trace: #0 {main} throw in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\scripts\createdb.php on line 8

i have posted in bitnami forum https://community.bitnami.com/t/error-after-install-wordpress-from-bitnami/39395/1

does anyone got this too? and how to solve this?

my OS : windows 8

Answer (score 0):

I have just noticed this message on the ApacheFriends website.

"We are working on making Bitnami add-ons available for PHP7, it is possible the current add-ons do not work well in version 7"

Downloading an earlier version resolved this issue.

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this same error when trying to install the module. Here's my quick fix:

1. Allow the module to download and continue on through the error
2. Inside your xampp folder maneuver through xampp>apache>conf to open http.conf with a text editor
3. At the very end insert the following:
   Include "C:/xampp/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
   replacing C:\ with the path to your xampp directory
4. Download the newest version of wordpress from [wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org)
5. Maneuver through xampp>apps>wordpress>htdocs and clear out the whole folder, most easily done by moving the htdocs folder to another location (recycling bin) and creating a new folder by the same name (make sure wp-config file is deleted)
6. Unzip the contents of the WordPress download and copy them over to the new or cleared htdocs folder
7. Restart your server and access the clean version of WordPress via browser to initiate the startup and installation

Comment: I know it's a dirty way of getting started but it's the best until bitnami gets around to updating their modules for php7